# Display OU of a computer on a network with multiple domains

Tags: networking, vbscript, get, ou

I'm really new to the VBscripting world, so please be gentle :) I'm trying to display the OU of a computer on a network which has 2 domains. I have a script to display the details of the local computer:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strComputerDN = objSysInfo.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strComputerDN)
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Wscript.Echo objComputer.distinguishedName
```

But I've had no luck with displaying the same for a computer name that I enter in an InputBox. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to query AD for that name. My [ADQuery](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml) class should get you around most of the boilerplate code required for this.

```
'<-- insert class code here

computer = ...

Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(sAMAccountName=" & computer & "$))"

Set obj = qry.Execute
Do Until obj.EOF
  WScript.Echo Split(obj("distinguishedName").Value, ",", 2)(1)
  obj.MoveNext
Loop
obj.Close
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply!! will test it out and see if it works for me!! Cheers :)

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggested script and I'm getting the error message Object required 'obj'. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again

Comment: If obj is `Nothing` (check with `WScript.Echo TypeName(obj)`) the query didn't find a matching object. Does the domain you're logged into actually have a matching computer object?

Comment: Yes the computer is on the domain I tried with 5 different computers and I'm getting the same error. line 401 char 1, Object required 'obj'. Cheers